# How to select most recent entry in MySQL db for an UPDATE statement

Tags: mysql

So, the statement below works fine, however it sets the relation.CompletedID value to the first completed.CompletedID value for the matching email. The problem is that this is a record of shopping carts, and one user may have multiple finished shopping carts. The goal is to correctly match up the completed cart to an entry on the relation table that also holds a unique value for abandoned carts and matching customer data.

```
UPDATE relation INNER JOIN completed ON relation.email = completed.email 
SET relation.CompletedID = completed.CompletedID, relation.hasconverted = 
IF(STRCMP(relation.hasbeenmailed,'YES'),'NO','YES')
```

The process for the rest of the columns is as such:

1. Customer comes to site, fills out cart and then leaves, triggering an aysnc post of cart data to server.
2. Server cleans and organizes post data and writes to MySQL db, creating a new entry in a table called abandoned and a new entry in a table called relation holding the unique id for the relation entry and the matching cart ID from the abandoned table.
3. Cron job checks abandoned table for entries with column "hasbeenmailed" not set to YES and schedules a reminder email for the customer with the abandoned cart.
4. Customer returns to site and completes cart. Site sends post data to server.
5. Server cleans and organizes post data and write to MySQL db, creating a new entry in a table called completed. The server then executes the code above to update relation to show conversion.

There are four tables:

- abandoned (holds unique entries for each abandoned cart, unique key is uuid)
- customer (holds unique entries for each customer, unique key is email)
- completed (holds unique entries for each completed cart, no unique key)
- relation (holds matching keys for each of the other tables and email status)

Not sure what else I should provide, but if anyone needs more info I can edit this post. Thanks for the help, this is one of the last bugs in this whole thing.

Here is a link to the SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/abdc5/1

Here is a statement that selects the correct entries:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `relation` 
WHERE ISNULL( CompletedID ) 
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: Can you write a SELECT query that returns the correct candidate for the UPDATE? Failing that, can you provide proper DDLs and/or an sqlfiddle TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT (of that select query)

Comment: Will add those to the post above, the tables in the sqlfiddle will be empty, but I can generate some sql statements to add data.

Comment: I wonder if I can use the uuid to link all of them together, as it is the only truly unique information across all of the tables.

Comment: LIMIT without ORDER BY doesn't mean much, so that *may* return the correct result - but more by luck than skill ;-)